# Finding which solution a file belongs to in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and somehow the people who created this project have a folder which contains files for multiple projects in a single solution.

Is there a way to find in which project in the solution explorer a file is included ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of Solution Explorer, you can use a utility like WinGrep to search all .csproj files (or if not using c#, whatever extension for your project files).

I do that type of thing all the time.  A project file is really just a text file that can be searched like any other text file.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was doing now, I was just wondering if I could find a solution that was within the box. I am currently working on a base code that is really messy.

Comment: I can't find any way to search all project files from within Visual Studio.  I think the best option is a text search from Windows Explorer.  It would be a nice thing for Microsoft to add to Visual Studio though.

Answer (score 0):

Since then I found that Microsoft Productivity Power Tools does this. When installing it you get a 'Solution Navigator' in the 'Solution Explorer' tab which allows you to search files and it will display to which project it belongs.

[Download](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)